# reconstruct a matrix from its row and column sums

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, matrix, language-agnostic

Take a n*m matrix filled with floating point values between 0 and 1.

Example:

```
0    0.5  0    0
0    0.5  1    0.4
0.2  1    0.3  0
0    1    0    0
```

The goal is to reconstruct the values in this matrix.

I do not have access to this matrix, so I do not know any of its values at the beginning.
There is a function to calculate each value, `calc_value(m,n)`. So a simple way to reconstruct this matrix is to call `calc_value(m,n)` for each value.
But calling this function is a very expensive operation, so I would like to call this function as few times as possible.

I know the *total sum of all values* in the matrix, and the *sum of values in each individual row and column*. (calculating each of these sums is no more expensive than a call to `calc_value(m,n)`)

**Using the row and column sums as additional information, how can I fill all values in the matrix with the least amount of calls to `calc_value()`?**

**Is it possible with fewer than `O(n*m)` calls?**

There is one additional constraint for the matrix that may help: the values in each row and column will be be monotonous increasing up to a maximum, then monotonous decreasing after that maximum. So a single row could look like this:

```
0 0.5 0.5 1 1 0.5 0
```

but not like this:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1
```

e.g. more than one distinct local maximum is not allowed

---

This is the status of my own attempts:

So far I discovered the following inequalities. For a given value of the matrix M(n,m):

```
M(n,m) <= Min ( sum_of_row_n, sum_of_column_m)
M(n,m) >= sum_of_row_n - sum_of_all_columns_except_m
M(n,m) >= sum_of_column_m - sum_of_all_rows_except_n
```

But these inequalities do not provide enough information to deduce the value M(n,m), except for some trivial cases.

Comment: If your matrix is represented as an array of arrays, accessing one element should be done in constant time, so what does the calc_value compute ?

Comment: I do not have the matrix at the start, my goal is to create this matrix. Once I have calculated each value, accessing it is of course a constant time operation

Comment: "The goal is to determine the values in this matrix." How can you do it if you don't have access to it ?

Comment: The values in the matrix represent some real-world property, but the exact relationship is hard to explain. So I am not just looking for an arbitrary marix, I am trying to reconstruct a particular matrix, given that I know all row and column sums and can calculate each individual value (with an expensive calculation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you describe it seems that your matrix has m*n degrees of freedom. The range and monotonicity constraints do not reduce the degrees of freedom. Each sum (row, column, total) removes one degree of freedom - until (m-1)*(n-1) degrees have been reached. (Since the sum of all row sums and the sum of all column sums equals the total sum you can only exploit m+n-1 of these constraints).

So with the given information all you can do is:

1. calculate the matrix elements a_ij, 1 <= i< m, 1 <=j < n with calc_value(i,j)
2. compute the missing element of each row/column and a_mn via the row/col sum properties