# All combinations of elements in a 2x2 matrix, with row and column sums equal to specified values

Tags: python, c, r, matrix, combinations

**Background**

I am trying to code Fisher's exact test (see: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)), specifically for 2 x 2 contingency tables (matrices). But I am stuck **on one particular step:** *to generate alternative matrices given an observed matrix of non-negative integers, where alternative matrices' row and column sums must be equal to the original matrix.* [This page (Wolphram)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FishersExactTest.html) has a description of all the steps, but below I will elaborate on the bit I am stuck on.

---

**Question**

In order to implement Fisher's exact test for 2 x 2 contingency tables I am given a 2 x 2 matrix whose elements are non-negative integers representing  observations, the *observed* matrix.

One of the steps requires me to generate all combinations of 2 x 2 matrices, the *alternative* matrices, whose non-negative integer elements are restricted by the following conditions:

- The dimensions of all alternative matrices are 2 x 2, i.e. equal to the observed matrix.
- The sum of each row of the alternative matrices must be equal to the corresponding sum of each row of the observed matrixm, i.e. sum of row 2 in the observed matric == sum of row 2 in each of the alternative matrices.
- The sum of each column of the alternative matrices must be equal to the corresponding sum of each column of the observed matrix.

To me the most obvious way to generate alternative matrices is to brute force all possible combinations of numbers in a 2 x 2 matrix, whose values are less than or equal to the sums of rows/columns of the observed matrix. Then iterate through these combinations filtering out combinations that fail to satisfy the conditions above.

**Edited: What is the fastest algorithm to generate all combinations of elements in a 2x2 matrix (*alternative* matrices), with row and column sums equal to those of the *observed* matrix?**

<s>Original: How can we implement this in either of the following languages: R, Python, C/C++, Matlab?</s>

---

**Example**

For an example application of the 2×2 test, let  X be a journal, say either Mathematics Magazine or Science, and let Y be the number of articles on the topics of mathematics and biology appearing in a given issue of one of these journals. If Mathematics Magazine has five articles on math and one on biology, and Science has none on math and four on biology, then the relevant matrix would be:

[image]

and all possible alternative matrices will then be:

[[image]w](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbYQY.png)

---

**Related posts**

- [Bootstrapping 4x4 Matrix with Fixed Row and Column Sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588495/bootstrapping-4x4-matrix-with-fixed-row-and-column-sums)
- [reconstruct a matrix from its row and column sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729456/reconstruct-a-matrix-from-its-row-and-column-sums)
- [Randomize matrix elements between two values while keeping row and column sums fixed (MATLAB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432577/randomize-matrix-elements-between-two-values-while-keeping-row-and-column-sums-f)

Comment: We ware no "do my homework" service! I'm afraid you have to do it yourself. And you should have smapped some more languages. Try implementiong in Brainfuck

Comment: @Olaf, to avoid unnecessaries I will focus on "do it yourself", I will edit the question to include my attempt. I am interested in this case of combinatorics because my hidden suspicion is that the most efficient solution is similar to that for solving sudoku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer using sympy. The idea is the same: Solve the linear system of equations you get from the sum of your matrix elements being row and column number. This is hardcoded in M. s is basically your matrix. linsolve gives you infinitelly many solutions and the rest restricts them to positive integers.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
from sympy.sets.fancysets import Naturals0
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_inequalities

M = Matrix([[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]])
s = Matrix([5,5,6,4])

a,b,c,d = symbols('a, b, c, d')
solution = linsolve((M,s), [a,b,c,d])

solution_eq = [x >= 0 for x in list(list(solution)[0])]
possible_values = reduce_inequalities(solution_eq, x.free_symbols)

for d_fixed in Intersection(possible_values.as_set(), Naturals0()):
    print solution.subs({d : d_fixed})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy. You simply need to select out of all possible combinations that ones that match the condition.

Here is a solution in python:

```
# [[i, j]
#  [k, l]]

def findAlternativeMatrices(c):
    # arg c = cont. matrix
    # this only works for integers
    alt = []
    # no single value inside an alternative matrix
    # can be bigger than the largest row/column-sum 
    N = max([c[0][0]+c[1][0],c[0][1]+c[1][1],c[0][0]+c[0][1], c[1][0]+c[1][1]])
    # loop over all matrix entries
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(N):
                for l in range(N):
                    #check if the respective sums equal
                    if(     (i+k == (c[0][0]+c[1][0]) )
                        and (j+l == (c[0][1]+c[1][1]) )
                        and (i+j == (c[0][0]+c[0][1]) )
                        and (k+l == (c[1][0]+c[1][1]) ) ):

                        if [[i,j],[k,l]] != c:
                            # append the matrix 
                            # if it isn't the given cont. matrix
                            alt.append([[i,j],[k,l]])

    return alt


c = [[5,0],[1,4]]
alt = findAlternativeMatrices(c)

for a in alt:
    print a
```